# can we store different values in same table based on if else condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, case-statement

```
if (@DiscountFrom = '100' and @DiscountUpto = '100')
begin  
   select id1.*, case when id1.Module_Type='sl' and id2.Module_Type = 'sl' and id1.Module_Code = id2.Module_Code and id1.Product_Code = id2.Product_Code and id2.Discount_Percentage = 0 and id2.Is_Inactive = 0 then id2.Quantity_Out else 0 end as BaseQuantity
   into #invoices2
   from batches id1
     right join batches id2 on id1.Module_Code = id2.Module_Code and id1.Product_Code = id2.Product_Code and id1.Discount_Percentage= '100'
    select * into #batches2 from #invoices2
    where BaseQuantity <> 0
    drop table #invoices2

    else 
    select * into #batches2 from Batches
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: Use `INSERT .. SELECT` not `SELECT INTO`. I fail to see the point of using `#invoices2` at all though, since it's deleted immediately. Perhaps you're looking for `INSERT INTO batches from ( select case .... from batches id1 right join batches .... )?

Comment: i used #invoices2 table to store data from batches and new column which i got from  case statement.... since that column also contain data that i do not need i filtered that data using this where clause 
' select * into #batches2 from #invoices2
    where BaseQuantity <> 0'
after that #invoices2 table is of no use.       but my question is can i assign data  of one table to the table out of two table based on condition

Comment: This seems to be way overcomplicated. But without actual details it is impossible to help.